# static resource cannot be resolved

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I am trying to implement MahApps style in my accounting system I follow the step needed here the link that I used [MahApps](http://mahapps.com/guides/quick-start.html#installation) .

Here is the  code that I have I stuck in a error the resource `appbar_cupcake` cannot be resolved here is the code

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="Hassab_Accounting_System.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>

</Grid>
<Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
<Controls:WindowCommands>
<Button Content="settings" />
<Button>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20"
               Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button},    Path=Foreground}">
      <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill"
                     Visual="{StaticResource appbar_cupcake}" />
      </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
    </Rectangle>
    <TextBlock Margin="4 0 0 0"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Text="deploy cupcakes" />
  </StackPanel>
  </Button>
  </Controls:WindowCommands>
  </Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
  </Controls:MetroWindow>
            `
   ![here is the error ][2]
```

[image: Exception]

Comment: make sure you install the resources also http://mahapps.com/guides/icons-and-resources.html

Comment: @nit I already installed:) the resources ...

Comment: have you included the resourcedictionary shown in the page?

Comment: @nit here is the exception that the compiler through Troubleshooting Exceptions: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException

Comment: what message this exception is giving?

Comment: @nit how I can do it? can you help

Comment: there must be some message associated with this exception or the inner exception.. can you check ?

Comment: @nit I updated the answer to upload the picture when I run the program

Comment: Where is the "StaticResource appbar_cupcake" defined?

Comment: the staticResource appbar_cupcake is defined in icon.xaml in folder called Resource

Comment: Ok, is it merged into the ResourceDictionary in the file where you use it?

Comment: Please, view the detail of your `Exception` (and preferably the inner `Exception`) and add the details to your question.

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Comment: actually no I could not solve it..\

Comment: Did you try my solution, by adding it to the App.xaml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you haven't done this already, since it is not included in the question, make sure you include the resource file, in your case icon.xaml in the ResourceDictionary at the top of your file.

Something like:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resource/icon.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Or to your App.xaml like:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
             <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resource/icon.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: actually I try your method but It give me another error that windows.resources is not accessible or recognized...

Comment: Is it a window you are writing? What is the root element? If it is a <Page> then replace <Window.Resource> with <Page.Resource>. Same thing goes for <UserControl>, <CustomControl> etc

Comment: actually I am using <Controls:MetroWindow/> I make it Controls:MetroWindow.Resources also it give me same thing the same error

Comment: Could you just post your entire XAML in the question?

Comment: Just a note, in the latest MahApps.Metro.Resources package, the path is /Resources/Icons.xaml

Comment: the App.xaml syntax that worked for me is `<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Icons.xaml" />`